# Add/remove class if full screen is on/off

Tags: jquery

I need to remove the class `.isfull` when not in full screen, and only add it when in full screen. Thanks

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).on('resize', function(){
    if(screen.width === window.innerWidth){
      $('#fullscreen-wrapper').addClass('isfull');
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: First why not just make an else statement where you remove the class? ?? If you don't want to do that you can make it like: 

inside you "resize" function try with `$('#fullscreen-wrapper').toggleClass('isfull', screen.width === window.innerWidth)` and then remove the if statement

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen This works, but when the class gets removed, some css I have doesn't update to what it was due to some other code I think. How can I do it so that it changes the class to `.isfull` or `.isntfull` instead? Thank you

Comment: '...due to some other code I think' - we can't debug that issue without knowing what the 'other code' is.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I know, I'm trying to keep it simple. Basically I am assigning some css to the `.isfull` class via jquery, so I need to override it with another class otherwise it doesn't clear up the style once outside full screen. I hope it makes sense.